# Connection pooling/limit for SQL Server and Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, ado.net, connection-pooling

I found this article regarding Linq-to-SQL and SQL Server connection pooling: [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2009/04/09/linq-to-sql-and-connection-pooling.aspx)

From what I assume from the article, is that Linq-to-SQL using the same Max Pool Size setting just as if it was an ADO object.

I have an C# app that is hitting the database pretty hard. Is there a way to tell if I am hitting my connection limit? How can I tell if my connections are being queued?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You should be interested in following counters:

- `NumberOfPooledConnections` - how many connections your pool mantain
- `NumberOfActiveConnections` - how many connections are in use
- `NumberOfFreeConnections` - how many connections are not in use

Last two counters require some modification in your [application configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254503%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#ActivatingOffByDefault).

[Another article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/CMouli/PerfCounters10142009095556AM/PerfCounters.aspx) about working with these counters.

Answer (score 1):

you could open a connection and execute this stored procedure; assuming you use sql server.

```
EXEC SP_WHO
```

you could compare all connections to the dbname with status != sleeping.

Comment: i found this interesting article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175863%28SQL.80%29.aspx